# How to handle 'CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down'? in redis cluster

Tags: redis

I created a redis cluster with three masters and each one has a single slave like below?
Master: 127.0.0.1 7000 127.0.0.1 7001 127.0.0.1 7002 
Slave: 127.0.0.1 7003 127.0.0.1 7004 127.0.0.1 7005 
Assumption that one master(127.0.0.1 7002) is down and recovered again after a while, why it appears 'CLUSTERDOWN The cluster is down' error message?

Best regards,
Xu Liang

Comment: See https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1869#issuecomment-48822415 for relevant information. The designed command to handle such cases should be [`CLUSTER FAILOVER`](http://redis.io/commands/cluster-failover)